# display canvas stream on video element javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've a video element and want to allow users to draw on canvas, capture canvas stream and display it on the video element, but the video displays black screen and I've no idea what I'm doing wrong, here's my code

```
const localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo')

class SignTool {
    constructor() {
        this.initVars()
        this.initEvents()
        this.currentColor = "white";
        this.resize(this.ctx);
    }
    
    initVars() {
        this.canvas = this.createCanvas()
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
        this.isMouseClicked = false
        this.isMouseInCanvas = false
        this.prevX = 0
        this.currX = 0
        this.prevY = 0
        this.currY = 0
    }
    
    initEvents() {
        this.canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {this.onMouseMove(e)}
        this.canvas.onmousedown = (e) => this.onMouseDown(e)
        this.canvas.onmouseup = () => this.onMouseUp()
        this.canvas.onmouseout = () => this.onMouseOut()
        this.canvas.onmouseenter = (e) => this.onMouseEnter(e)
        let canvasStream = this.canvas.captureStream();
        localVideo.srcObject = canvasStream;
        localVideo.onloadedmetadata = () => {
            localVideo.play();
        }
    }
    
    onMouseDown(e) {
        this.isMouseClicked = true
        this.updateCurrentPosition(e)
    }

    createCanvas() {
        const canvasDiv = document.querySelector('.canvas-holder')

        // create canvas element and append it to document body
        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = "canvas"
        canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
        // some hotfixes... ( ≖_≖)
        canvas.style.position = 'fixed';
        return canvas
    }
    
    onMouseUp() {
        this.isMouseClicked = false
    }
    
    onMouseEnter(e) {
        this.isMouseInCanvas = true
        this.updateCurrentPosition(e)
    }
    
    resize(ctx) {
        ctx.canvas.width = localVideo.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        ctx.canvas.height = localVideo.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    }
    
    onMouseOut() {
        this.isMouseInCanvas = false
    }
    
    onMouseMove(e) {
        if (this.isMouseClicked && this.isMouseInCanvas) {
            this.updateCurrentPosition(e)
        this.draw()
        }
    }
    
    updateCurrentPosition(e) {
        this.prevX = this.currX
        this.prevY = this.currY
        this.currX = e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft
        this.currY = e.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop
    }
    
    draw() {
        this.ctx.beginPath()
        this.ctx.moveTo(this.prevX, this.prevY)
        this.ctx.lineTo(this.currX, this.currY)
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.currentColor
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 2
        this.ctx.stroke()
        this.ctx.closePath()
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
    new SignTool()
})
```

the video displays black screen, showing controls apparently it shows audio track counting but black screen
I can draw on the canvas, calling `canvas.toDataUrl` gives a valid url of the canvas image

Comment: And you can see the drawings on the canvas?

Comment: can you insert a working code snippet?

Comment: yes, the canvas is being drawn on, and printing canvas.toDataUrl gives a valid url of canvas image

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/9rhwxn8k/